# APEX 5 Authorization Scheme specific user

Tags: oracle, authorization, oracle-apex-5

I am building an APEX 5 Application for a school. There is a page called "Course Information" and it includes several Classic Reports with information such as the class roster and testing schedule. I want to include a report with grades but I only want this region to be viewable by the teacher of the course. If I can get a hidden item on the page to be filled with the username of the teacher, can I build an authorization scheme that checks APP_USER against this item and only show the region if they match?

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I would go about this slightly differently, and wouldn't use an Authorization Scheme for this particular requirement.

1. Base the report on a view which has the teacher's username as one of the columns. Put a where clause in the report SQL, e.g. `select col1, col2, col3 from the_view where teacher_username = :APP_USER`.
2. Put a Condition on the region using **Rows returned** based on something like `select 1 from the_view where teacher_username = :APP_USER`.

This way, the report region will only be rendered if the user is allowed to view the records in it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use server side condition, a function that returns Boolean, for that region. Just put

```
return :APP_USER = 'YOUR_TEACHER';
```

in there. Region will render only for your teacher. Of course, 'YOUR_TEACHER' should be substituted with his real username.

Comment: Okay so I created an item names P1_USER and for now just make it a static value equal to 'ADAMS'. Then I created the authorization scheme PL/SQL Function returning a boolean to return :APP_USER = :P1_USER; but it did not work @littlefoot

Comment: That's not what I said, @Jordan. Select region. On right hand side, under region properties, scroll down to "Server-side condition". Type = "PL/SQL function body". Put `return :APP_USER = 'JORDAN';` in there (or whatever your username is). When you run the page, you'll see the region. Then change JORDAN to LITTLEFOOT and run the page again - region won't be visible. Authorization scheme is something different - Jeffrey described it in his answer so - have a look, try both (why not?) so that you'd see the differences.